# Django admin sharing inlines between apps

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a few apps in my project that I want to be reusable.

First, I have a base content App, which defines how content can be added to a ContentContainer.  This allows other models to inherit ContentContainer to get the ability to show content.

Within the content app, I have a Page model that inherits ContentContainer.  In another app called events, I have an Event model that also inherites ContentContainer.  Basically, my events app depends on my content app (Which is what I want).

This all works great in modeling.  I have this in my content app:

```
class ContentContainer(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #No fields, it just gets referred to by ContentItem

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['modified']

class ContentItem(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1500)
    page_order = models.IntegerField()
    container = models.ForeignKey(ContentContainer, blank=True)

    #make inheritance know the model type
    objects = InheritanceManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = [ 'page_order', 'modified', 'name']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def render(self):
        return self.name


class TextContent(ContentItem):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=5000000)

    def render(self):
        return '<p>%s</p>' % self.text
```

Then in my Events app I do this:

```
class Event(AnnouncementBase, Addressable, ContentContainer):
    cost = CurrencyField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, blank=True, default=0.00)
    start_date = models.DateField(default = datetime.now().date())
    start_time = models.TimeField(default = datetime.now().time())
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, default=None, null = True)
    end_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, default=None, null = True)
    rsvp_deadline = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, default=None, null = True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['start_date', 'start_time', 'title']
```

So now events can have content to render.

Here's where things get confusing.  I have a slew of inlines defined in admin.py in the content app.  They work great there.  Also, if I copy an paste them into admin.py in the events app they work there too.

However, I don't want to duplicate code.  I want to import the inlines from admin.py into events.py In contents admin.py I have this:

```
class TextContentInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = models.TextContent
    extra = 1

class PageAdmin(ContainerAdmin):
    model = models.Page
    inlines = [LinkContentInline, TextContentInline]
```

There are a bunch of these inlines.  How can I share them between my admin.py models?  If I try to import them in the events admin.py I get an error that says "The model Page is already registered".  I've tried about 5 different things I could think of an none of them work.  I am wondering if there is no way to do this.  Oh I'm using Django 1.3 too.

Comment: question, are you importing inlines or PageAdmin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "already registered" error happens because when a module is imported, Python executes all the statements in the top level - and one of those is the `admin.site.register`, which is therefore called multiple times.

It's easy to fix this - just catch the exception and ignore it:

```
try:
    admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
except admin.sites.AlreadyRegistered:
    pass
```

An alternative is to keep your inline classes in a completely separate module file - `admin_inlines.py`, perhaps - and import them from there into every admin that needs them.

Comment: I moves the linelines into a file called admin_inlines.  Then I made a constant list called CONTENT_INLINES and just imported that for use in the two admin models.  This way if I ever add more inlines I just have to change the one constant.  Thanks for the great answer, I would vote it up bu I don;t have enough rep yet.